# X forwarding works from Cygwin shell, but not with PuTTY

Tags: cygwin, xforwarding

As subject, I've X forwarding working from a Windows client if I use the Cygwin terminal and do:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ssh -Y me@remote-host
```

If I were to use PuTTY from the same Windows host (checked *Enable X forwarding*, set *X display location* to `:0`) and run, say, `xclock` from the terminal, I get connection refused. I wondered what I'm missing.

The only reason I'm looking to get PuTTY is that the Cygwin console has a rather noticeable refresh lag.

Comment: Are you running the Xserver ? Have you open the Xserver for TCP connection ? Cygwin Terminal and Putty are not X application just console one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to have the server [listen to TCP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58549/101463). Once the server is launched, determine server location by hovering over X server icon in the system tray, and configure PuTTY to use X forwarding, with the server port and XAuthority file, which can be found out from  Cygwin terminal: `echo $(cygpath -w $HOME)/.Xauthority`.

In short, append this to X server's command line (in the launch shortcut icon):

```
-- -multiwindow -listen tcp
```

Sadly, this has to be done every time you update Cygwin's X, as the shortcut will be overwritten during the update.